# Using WebInvoke to POST data in WCF WebApi

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-web-api

I've recently started using [WCF WebApi](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) to create a REST api. I followed samples available on CodePlex and also [articles series](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/04/15/Microsoft-Web-API-e28093-the-REST-is-done-by-WCF-%28Part-1%29.aspx) by Alex Zeitler.

I tried to create a method which accepts data via POST as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class AuthenticateApi
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]  
    public HttpResponseMessage<LoginModel> Post(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        loginModel.IsValidated = true;
        return new HttpResponseMessage<LoginModel>(loginModel);
    }
}
```

And this is my Entity:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidated { get; set; }
}
```

And finally this is my configuration in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapServiceRoute<AuthenticateApi>("login");
}
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

When I try to POST something using Fiddler this way:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{"Username": "mahdi", "Password":"123"}
Host: localhost:8181
```

I receive the following error message:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
>   Parameter name: name'. See server logs for more details. The exception
>   stack trace is:
>
> at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckBadChars(String name, Boolean
>   isHeaderValue) at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name,
>   String value) at
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(NameValueCollection
>   c) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.HostedRequestContainer.System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.IHttpHeaderProvider.CopyHeaders(WebHeaderCollection
>   headers) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.get_Headers()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Channels.HttpMessageEncodingRequestContext.ConfigureRequestMessage(Message
>   message) in
>   F:\codeplex\wcf\Http\Src\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http\Microsoft\ApplicationServer\Http\Channels\HttpMessageEncodingRequestContext.cs:line
>   222 at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Channels.HttpMessageEncodingRequestContext.get_RequestMessage()
>   in
>   F:\codeplex\wcf\Http\Src\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http\Microsoft\ApplicationServer\Http\Channels\HttpMessageEncodingRequestContext.cs:line
>   54 at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EnsureChannelAndEndpoint(RequestContext
>   request) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryRetrievingInstanceContext(RequestContext
>   request)

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Where exactly do yo pass that JSON object? From your example it looks like you pass it in message header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the JSON object in the request body field, not in with the headers.

Comment: @Mahdi: If you open request builder in Fiddler there is part for Request headers and Request Body!